# Creating Calendar Events for Other Users

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I've dug around and I'm not finding anything specific that points to this.  Is is possible to create calendar events in other user calendars?  Our company has Google Apps, so everyone is in our domain.  Everything I'm finding points to the other user being required to approve the calendar events.

The end results that I'm tasked with is when an employee has approved time off, that it is sent to the employee and supervisor calendars.  I'm sure there is something out there, I'm just not having any luck finding it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a service account to impersonate users to achieve this. You can find the documentation on how to do this authorization [right here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Once you have completed the domain wide delegation, you can use something like this to achieve your task:

```
<?php

session_start();

//INCLUDE PHP CLIENT LIBRARY
require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.0.3/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=yourkey.json'); // yourkey = the name of your json client secret file.

//set the required scopes
$scopes = array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");

// Create client object
$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope($scopes);

$client->setSubject("user@thedomain.com");

$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);    

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => 'Test Event',
    'location' => 'Some Location',
    'description' => 'Google API Test Event',
    'start' => array(
      'dateTime' => '2017-04-12T05:00:00-06:00'   
    ),
    'end' => array(
      'dateTime' => '2017-04-12T05:25:00-06:00'
    ),  
    'reminders' => array(
      'useDefault' => FALSE,
      'overrides' => array(
        array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
        array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10)
      ),
    ),
    'attendees' => array(
      array('email' => 'userone@domain.com'),
      array('email' => 'usertwo@domain.com')
    )
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $cal->events->insert($calendarId, $event, array('sendNotifications' => TRUE));

printf('Event created: %s<br>', $event->htmlLink);    

?>
```

Please note: The above example is executed using the Google API PHP client library. For other examples, consult the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!  Service accounts definitely looks like what I was looking for. :)